# how can i list in html names in textarea

Tags: jquery, html

How can i catch id tags and write into p. I want to list id names in to textarea inputs.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<textarea id="textid" class="textclass">
    <div id="hello"><span id="world"></span></div>
</textarea>
  <p></p>
```

JS

```
$("textarea").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
 }).keyup();
```

Sample
http://jsfiddle.net/6YRyP/2/

Comment: So you want what: textid or hello + world ???

Comment: i want to see "hello world"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to parse the text from textarea into HTML (as @roasted proposes) you can try using regular expressions:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();
     val = '';

     matches = value.match(/id="[^"]*/g);

     for (i in matches) {
         val += matches[i].substr(4) + ' ';
     }

     $("p").text(val);
}).keyup();
```

Comment: Both of the approaches have pros and cons. Some cons: when using regular expressions you can match any text which will contain `id="` and when using DOM objects you have to be sure you've got valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6YRyP/8/)

```
$("textarea").keyup(function () {
    var $content = $($('<div/>').html($.trim(this.value))),
        ids = "";
    $content.find('[id]').each(function(){
        ids += " "+ this.id;
    });

    $("p").text(ids.substring(0));
}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one way to do it : http://jsfiddle.net/6YRyP/7/

```
$("textarea").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('body').append('<div id="search">'+value+'</div>');
    var listOfId = "";
    $('*', $('#search')).each(function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (currentId != "") {
           listOfId = listOfId + currentId + ' ';
        }
    });
    $('#search').remove();
    $("p").text(listOfId);
}).keyup();
```